# Is it possible to query a running Spring Batch application in order to check Jobs status?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am working on a Spring Batch application. I deployed this application on a production Linux server as ajar file that I runned as a normal jar application. My Spring Batch application is up and running, infact my **UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** seems to be up and running as process:

```
webadmin@webadmin.myserver.it [~]# ps aux | grep java
webadmin  4677  0.1  3.2 10255180 809528 ?     Sl   Nov17  12:10 java -jar UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
webadmin  5152  0.0  0.0 112812   980 pts/1    S+   09:58   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

My application contains two Jobs definition scheduled at a specific time using a CRON expression:

```
/**
 * This bean schedules and runs our Spring Batch job.
 */
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("launcher")
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
    private Job updateNotaryDistrictsJob;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
    private Job updateNotaryListInfoJob;
   
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expresion.runUpdateNotaryListInfoJob}")
    public void runUpdateNotaryListInfoJob() {
        LOGGER.info("SCHEDULED run of updateNotaryListInfoJob STARTED");
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(updateNotaryListInfoJob, jobParameters);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expresion.runUpdateNotaryDistrictJob}")
    public void runUpdateNotaryDistrictsJob() {
        LOGGER.info("SCHEDULED run of updateNotaryDistrictsJob STARTED");
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(updateNotaryDistrictsJob, jobParameters);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    

    private JobParameters newExecution() {
        Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(new Date());
        parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);

        return new JobParameters(parameters);
    }
    
}
```

Now I am asking if there are some way to interact with this running application in order to check if some errors occurs during the lasts executions of the jobs defined into this application. Is it possible to query my running application asking for jobs status or something like this?

Comment: That is what the database tables are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Spring Batch database tables for this check the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html